# Change text of HTML5 draggable element's "clone" while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

I'm trying to set the text of an HTML5 draggable element's clone (the one that appears when you start to drag and lasts till you end the drag) to something different than its text node when it's dragging.

Consider this example: http://jsfiddle.net/dwpLzuh5/

I've tried (using other examples on the internet as inspiration) to set the data/text via `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData()` hoping to change the "cloned" element text to *"dragging"* but nothing seems to happen.

Am I doing something wrong or this is simply not possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your jsfiddle ever so slightly to get it working, check it out. I have just sent the $(this) into the function. do the same but reverse to reset text back to normal.

```
function startTheDrag(e){
    console.log('dragging');

    e.text("dragging");
};

$(".draggable").on('dragstart', function(){
    startTheDrag($(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwpLzuh5/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is kind of what I needed.